# Master / Detail prevent Detail combination

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

Assumed you have a master table, with some data

```
MasterId    MasterData
--------    ----------
1           data1
2           data2
3           data3
```

and a detail table which is referencing the master

```
DetailId    DetailMasterId     DetailKind    DetailData
--------    --------------     ----------    ----------
1           1                  A             detailData1
2           1                  B             detailData2
3           2                  C             detailData3
4           1                  C             detailData4
```

Is there a way to define some invalid combinations, based on SQL-Server capabilities? Imagine you don't want allow a detailcombination of detailKind A and C to the same Master. I want to prevent these from occurring at the SQL level.

I can use a trigger, but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: It will help if you provided input and desired solution. For example, (A,C) is the input, what should or should not happen for given data?

Comment: @Bulat if there is already an A-Detail then a C-Detail cant be inserted and visa-versa

Comment: it depends on the current code that you already have. is it within a procedure? how many different functions/procedures insert into this `detail` table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60961/discussion-between-bulat-and-deterministicfail).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to overcame the limit of the `CHECK` constraint if you don't want to use trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ExistsDetailKind(
    @MasterID INT, @DetailKind VARCHAR(10)
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (-- <Put your logic here>)
        return 1
    return 0
END

ALTER TABLE detail 
WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT CK_DetailTypes 
CHECK (ExistsDetailKind(DetailMasterId, DetailKind) = 0)
```